# Back button of Angular js Directive not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Several pages in my **AngularJS** webapp are being created through a custom directive that I wrote. The browser back button in all pages where the directive is not used works as expected(pressing the back button loads the previous page).
But in the case of the custom directive web pages, pressing the browser back button just reloads the current page that its in.

How do I get the back button to work as expected in the custom directive pages?
Do I have to inject any angular services, or do i have to write my own function
to handle the back button event?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you post what your directive is doing? It looks like you are changing `window.location` property somehow in your directive and Back button visually refreshes page where in reality it returns previous value of `location` property

Comment: Thanks! I checked the controller code and it was modifying $location.url. once i took that out, it worked.

Comment: Posted it as answer so you can mark question as answered in order to keep it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are changing `window.location` property somehow in your directive and Back button visually refreshes page where in reality it returns previous value of `location` property